# Can't find my connection string tag in web.config file in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, connection-string

I have just started working in ASP.NET MVC for learning purposes. I have been following a tutorial where it gives the brief about `web.config` file content and it tells about the connection string. But I can't find any connection string in my `web.config` file. Is this a big problem or we can add manually a connection string tag and then add our connection string to it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Any guide what possibly wrong could be there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply add it manually like this

```
<connectionStrings>

  <add name="myDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=MyDataBaseName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and change the `Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB` according to your database location and `Initial Catalog=MyDataBaseName` for your Databasename

see [Creating a Connection String and Working with SQL Server LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string)